# Change timer interval in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, timer

I have timer job inside a windows service, for which the interval should be incremented when errors occur. My problem is that I can't get the timer.Change Method to actually change the interval. The "DoSomething" is always called after the initial interval.

Code follows:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
 //job = new CronJob();
 timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(DoSomething);
 seconds = secondsDefault;
 stateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 0, seconds * 1000);
}
public void DoSomething(object stateObject)
{
 AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateObject;
 if(!Busker.BitCoinData.Helpers.BitCoinHelper.BitCoinsServiceIsUp())
    {
  secondsDefault += secondsIncrementError;
  if (seconds >= secondesMaximum)
   seconds = secondesMaximum;
  Loggy.AddError("BitcoinService not available. Incrementing timer to " +
                   secondsDefault + " s",null);

  stateTimer.Change(seconds * 100, seconds * 100);
  return;
 }
 else if (seconds > secondsDefault)
 {
  // reset the timer interval if the bitcoin service is back up...
  seconds = secondsDefault;
  Loggy.Add ("BitcoinService timer increment has been reset to " + 
                 secondsDefault + " s");
 }
 // do the the actual processing here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual problem is in this line:

```
secondsDefault += secondsIncrementError;
```

It should be:

```
seconds += secondsIncrementError;
```

Furthermore, The [`Timer.Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx) method operates in miliseconds, so multiplying by 100 is obviously wrong. That means change:

```
stateTimer.Change(seconds * 100, seconds * 100);
```

To

```
stateTimer.Change(seconds * 1000, seconds * 1000);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `stateTimer.Change(0, seconds * 100);` this will immediately force `System.Threading.Timer` to restart with new interval.